# How to create Multicolor TextEditor in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios6, uitextfield

I am creating TextEditor application in iphone sdk. In my app I like to change the color and font when ever the user needs while editing the text. For creating this I have refer some of the following library

1. Ego TextView-It allowed to change different font but setcolor property is not available
2. RichTextKit - SetKeyboard, setAutoCorrent is not available

But non of them is worked for  me. Can any one suggest some idea to create multiple color and multiple font TextEditor in iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 1):

For multiple font and multiple color, You can go for CG or even NSAttributedString.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:@"colorfull text"];
[attributedString setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
[attributedString setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[attributedString setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(3,7)];
```